# Problema con Jquery con if de estilo

Tags: jquery, css, animación

Hola estoy tratando de mostrar y ocultar en función de donde haga clic.
No me esta generando ningún tipo de error.

La intención es que al hacer clic se abra el input lo cual lo hace pero cuando aplico el if, else no hace nada, y al hacer clic fuera de el pues que desaparezca.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lupa").on('click', function(){
        //alert("Fue presionado.");
        //$('#buscador-text').slideToggle('swing');
        var buscador = $("#buscador-text").css;
        if(buscador.display == 'none'){
         buscador.animate({ width: "toggle", opacity: "1", left: '170px', display:'inline-block'}, "swing");
        }
        else if (buscador.display == 'inline-block') {
   buscador.animate({ width: "toggle", opacity: "1", left: '70px', display:'inline-block'}, "swing");

        }
      
    });
});
```

```css
#buscador{
 width: 40%;
 margin: 0.7em 4em;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}
input[type='search']{
  font-size: 1rem !important;
  margin-top: -0.8em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -2em;
  opacity: 0;
 }
span{
  padding-right: 1em;
 }
#buscador-text{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <section id="buscador">
  <span id="lupa"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span><input id="buscador-text" type="search" name="buscador" placeholder="Buscar...">
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas. Primero, `$("#buscador-text").css` no te va a devolver un string. Lo que buscas en realidad es `$("#buscador-text").css('display')`.

Segundo, después de la animación que le das, el objeto queda con `display:block`. (No entiendo por qué) así que la condición de ser igual a `inline-block` nunca se cumplirá a menos que, a continuación del `animate` fijes explícitamente esa propiedad.

El siguiente código me funciona:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {



  $("#lupa").on('click', function () {
      var buscador =$("#buscador-text"),
      display = buscador.css('display');

    if (display === 'none') {
      buscador.animate({
        width: "toggle",
        opacity: "1",
        left: '170px',
        display: 'inline-block'
      }, "swing").css('display','inline-block');
    } else {
      buscador.animate({
        width: "toggle",
        opacity: "1",
        left: '70px',
        display: 'none'
      }, "swing");

    }
  });

});
```

```css
#buscador{
 width: 40%;
 margin: 0.7em 4em;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}
input[type='search']{
  font-size: 1rem !important;
  margin-top: -0.8em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -2em;
  opacity: 0;
 }
span{
  padding-right: 1em;
 }
#buscador-text{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
    left:70px;
 }
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <section id="buscador">
  <span id="lupa"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span><input id="buscador-text" type="search" name="buscador" placeholder="Buscar...">
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacerlo de esta manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lupa").on('click', function(){
        var buscador = $("#buscador-text");
        if(!buscador.is(':visible')){
            buscador.animate({ width: "toggle", opacity: "1", left: '170px', display:'inline-block'}, "swing");
        }
        else{
            buscador.animate({ width: "toggle", opacity: "1", left: '70px', display:'inline-block'}, "swing");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#buscador{
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0.7em 4em;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
input[type='search']{
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    margin-top: -0.8em;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -2em;
    display: none;
}
span{
    padding-right: 1em;
}
#buscador-text{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="buscador">
  <span id="lupa"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
  <input id="buscador-text" type="search" name="buscador" placeholder="Buscar...">
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

var buscador = $("#buscador-text").css("display");
if(buscador == 'none'){
buscador.animate({ width: "toggle", opacity: "1", left: '170px',                display:'inline-block'}, "swing");
}
else if (buscador == 'inline-block') {
buscador.animate({ width: "toggle", opacity: "1", left: '70px', display:'inline-block'}, "swing");
});
});

Comment: Por favor lee la sección de [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), recuerda que tu respuesta debe ir explicada, no sólo el código, además para mayor legibilidad puedes darle formato de acuerdo a las reglas de MarkDown e incluso en casos como este que son respuestas de HTML, JS o CSS se puede insertar un snipet